# How Can I Trigger An Email Notification To Purchaser in WP-Ecommerce Using WP-Ecommerce-Shopstyling When An Order Is Submitted?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to trigger two emails during the check out process of WP-Ecommerce and have them styled using your awesome plugin.

1. Order Submitted - not sending anything to the buyer at the moment
2. Accepted Payment - working and styled using "wp-ecommerce-shopstyling"

Can you help me out with this? I would really love to be able to have an email sent to the buyer when they submit their order.

My client takes offline credit card payments, so I would like the buyer to know their order was sent (and is waiting for processing), and then the order was paid for and being created - the shop is a flower shop.

Currently the 'accepted payment' step works. But the submitted step, isn't sending anything. Any help would be awesome.

Cheers,
Fiona

Answer (score 0):

The email trigger is part of the WP E-Commerce core functionality. The Shop-Styling plugin just adds a nice formatting to the existing mail.
Your customers receive an email when they submit their order and as soon as you change the payment status to "payment accepted". This is the intended behavior.

You can use a hook in your themes function.php:

```
add_action('wpsc_update_purchase_log_status', 'triggerStatusChangeMail', 9, 4 );
function triggerStatusChange($id, $status, $old_status, $purchase_log ) {
  //      WPSC_Purchase_Log::INCOMPLETE_SALE  //= 1;
  //      const ORDER_RECEIVED   = 2;
  //      const ACCEPTED_PAYMENT = 3;
  //      const JOB_DISPATCHED   = 4;
  //      const CLOSED_ORDER     = 5;
  //      const PAYMENT_DECLINED = 6;
  //      const REFUNDED         = 7;
  //      const REFUND_PENDING   = 8;
  if ($status==2){
      wp_mail(...);
  }
}
```

You can use HTML code in your mail content and the Mail-Template will also be applied to your custom email automatically, but you cannot use any placeholders. If you want to add customer or order details in your mail you have to query all information from the database.

[Same questions in the comments of my website](http://haet.at/wp-e-commerce-shop-styling/#comment-1794)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

ACCEPTED_PAYMENT = 3 - is happening.
ORDER_RECEIVED   = 2 - is not happening.

Is the IF statement "wp_mail(...);" the place at which I would enter the email content for that event?